# Use of regressors with TBATS model from forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting

Does anyone know if it is possible to use regressors with the TBATS model in the R `forecast` package?

From the help file it looks like you can add additional parameters for ARMA and since ARIMA takes regressors (i.e `xreg = X` ) I was wondering if I could pass regressors to TBATS if I use ARMA  (`using.arma.erros=TRUE`) in my TBATS model.

Im still a pretty new R use so I would really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The `xreg` argument will be used when selecting the order of the ARMA model for the errors, but then it will be ignored when doing the estimation and forecasting.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Would it be unreasonable to use TBATS (without ARMA and regressors) to extract the timeseries seaosality (daily data with weekly and yearly seasonality) then feed the TBATS model errors into a secondary ARIMIA model with regressors?

Comment: That depends on whether the regressors have trend and seasonality. It might work ok provided the regressors are largely orthogonal to trend and seasonality. But you might be better off handling trend and seasonality within the ARIMA model more directly (e.g., via Fourier terms).

Answer (score -2):

I think TBATS does not accept regressors but only one regressor and that is the time which may be days, hours, years etc